# Convert number DDMMYY into date?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript (but not programming) and am having a difficult time figuring out where I made a mistake in this function, found here: http://mikeryan.webatu.com/function.html *[dead link][Guessing of the original code at the bottom]*

The function should take a **DDMMYY** timestamp and convert it into a **human-readable string**. For instance, **`210710`** would be turned into **`July 21st, 2010`**.

**UPDATE: Code that is probably similar OP's dead link:**

```
function timestamp(d){
    var year = (d-(Math.round(d / 100)*100);

    var day = Math.floor(d/10000);
    var dayfix = (day - (Math.floor(day/10)*10));

    // var month = ((d-year)-(day*100000)/100);

    var a = (d - year);
    var b = ((day * 100000) / 10);

    var month = (a - b) / 100;

    var months = new Array();
    months[1]  = "January";
    months[2]  = "February";
    months[3]  = "March";
    months[4]  = "April";
    months[5]  = "May";
    months[6]  = "June";
    months[7]  = "July";
    months[8]  = "August";
    months[9]  = "September";
    months[10]  = "October";
    months[11] = "November";
    months[12] = "December";

    var daysuffix = new Array();
    daysuffix[0] = "th";
    daysuffix[1] = "st";
    daysuffix[2] = "nd";
    daysuffix[3] = "rd";
    daysuffix[4] = "th";
    daysuffix[5] = "th";
    daysuffix[6] = "th";
    daysuffix[7] = "th";
    daysuffix[8] = "th";
    daysuffix[9] = "th";

    if(year>20){
       year = '19' + year;
    }
    else{
       year = '20' + year;
    }
    return (months[month] + ' ' + day + daysuffix[dayfix] + ', ' + year);
 }
```

Comment: why not turn the 210710 into a string and then do parseNumber on substrings to get your values?  Might be less efficient, but seems easier to think about.

Comment: Have you looked at JS's [Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)?

Comment: You accepted an answer, but I provided one using the Date object it check it out and also check out the link NullUserException has.  Using the date object might be easier then trying to parse the data yourself.

Comment: Please quote your code in the actual question as third party hosts can't be trusted for security or for futureproofing the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem: you're missing a parenthesis. Change:

```
var year = (d-(Math.round(d / 100)*100);
```

to

```
var year = (d-(Math.round(d / 100)*100));
```

That being said, this is a more straightforward calculation method:

```
var year = d % 100;
var month = Math.floor(d / 100) % 100;
var day = Math.floor(d / 10000) % 100;
```

Next, your array initialization is unnecessarily verbose. Instead of:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = "foo";
arr[1] = "bar";
```

just do:

```
var arr = ["foo", "bar"];
```

Your day suffix is incorrect. It puts "nd" after 12 and "12nd April" clearly isn't correct. I would just use logic for doing this rather than a lookup array where most elements are "th".

So:

```
function timestamp(d){
  var year = d % 100;
  var month = Math.floor(d / 100) % 100;
  var day = Math.floor(d / 10000) % 100;
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  if (year>20) {
    year = '19' + year;
  } else {
    year = '20' + year;
  }
  if (day == 1 || day == 21 || day == 31) {
    var suffix = "st";
  } else if (day == 2 || day == 22) {
    var suffix = "nd";
  } else {
    var suffix = "th";
  }
  return (months[month-1] + ' ' + day + suffix + ', ' + year);
}
```

Lastly there is little value in your "timestamp" being an integer in its present form. A more typical format for tis kind of thing is YYYYMMDD for two reasons:

1. Numerical ordering matches date ordering; and
2. It's unambiguous. North Americans put month before day (ie MMDDYY). Everyone else in the world puts day first (ie DDMMYY). No one does YYDDMM.

Comment: Yup, I'm tired and totally missed that one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, cletus! Your edited reply was extremely helpful, and a great learning experience for me.

Comment: The only reason I had chosen to go with an integer in the first place was to do time comparisons in a later function, to determine the amount of time between two dates. As for the second point, I realized that mistake earlier and have changed it on the server. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `%` - modulo: X modulo 100 discards anything except the last 2 digits. Useful!

also use `floor` not `round`

Answer (score 0):

Use the date object.  It's a whole lot faster.  Here is a quick example it assumes the year is going to be in the 2000s so you would have to do some modifications.  And the output is not exactly what you have, but it is pretty close and the code is a whole lot shorter.

```
function date(e){
  var d = new Date();
  d.setYear(2000+e.substring(4)/1,e.substring(2,4)-1,e.substring(0,2)-1);
  alert(d.toDateString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First use Math.floor to get the floor value of the decimal, then there were some typos in your function. Here is the code that works (Note: just tested with a couple of examples) but should be enough to get your started:

```
          function timestamp(d){
        var year = (d-(Math.floor(d / 100)*100));

        var day = Math.floor(d/10000);
        var dayfix = (day - (Math.floor(day/10)*10));

        // var month = ((d-year)-(day*100000)/100);

        var a = (d - year);
        var b = ((day * 100000) / 10);

        var month = (a - b) / 100;

        var months = new Array();
        months[1]  = "January";
        months[2]  = "February";
        months[3]  = "March";
        months[4]  = "April";
        months[5]  = "May";
        months[6]  = "June";
        months[7]  = "July";
        months[8]  = "August";
        months[9]  = "September";
        months[10]  = "October";
        months[11] = "November";
        months[12] = "December";

        var daysuffix = new Array();
        daysuffix[0] = "th";
        daysuffix[1] = "st";
        daysuffix[2] = "nd";
        daysuffix[3] = "rd";
        daysuffix[4] = "th";
        daysuffix[5] = "th";
        daysuffix[6] = "th";
        daysuffix[7] = "th";
        daysuffix[8] = "th";
        daysuffix[9] = "th";

        if(year>20){
           year = '19' + year;
        }
        else{
           year = '20' + year;
        }
        return (months[month] + ' ' + day + daysuffix[dayfix] + ', ' + year);
     }
```