# How to separate and rotate numbers in integer?

Tags: java

I have a small problem. I think it's simple, but I don't know, how to manage it properly.

I have this simple int:

```
int birth = 011112;
```

and I want **output** to look like this, in this specific format.

```
"Your birth date is 12.11.01."
```

I did it with an integer array, but I want only one integer input like this one, not an array.

Could some body help me? Is there any simple method to manage it of, without using loops?

Comment: There is a problem here that you seem to not be aware of. Try to print `birth`. What do you see?

Comment: An `int` is definitely not suitable for your needs. Take the input as a `String` instead for example.

Comment: I know, that, the null in the first position will make problem, but i want it to make some string and switch it, like it´s in the output.

Comment: Sure, you can do that. Take the input as a `String` as I suggested. After that, I would usually say to parse it to an actual date (`LocalDate` for example), but since this looks like homework, this is probably not what you should do. In your case, you could then use the [`String#substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) method to split up and rearrange your substrings to build your result string.

Comment: When an int literal starts with 0, it means that the number is _octal_, so `011112` is actually `4682` in decimal system.  What is the format in `birth`: `yyMMdd`, `ddMMyy`, `MMddyy` and which output format you expect?

Comment: If this is for the fun of the exercise, fine. For production code you should unconditionally keep your birth date in a `LocalDate` and nowhere else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert number DDMMYY into date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296105/convert-number-ddmmyy-into-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the conversion of the `int` representing a date in some format into String should use divide `/` and modulo `%` operations, conversion to String may use `String.format` to provide leading 0.

The number starting with 0 is written in *octal* notation, where the digits in range `0-7` are used, so the literals like `010819` or `080928` cannot even be written in Java code as `int` because of the compilation error:

```
error: integer number too large
    int birth = 010819;
```

However, (only for the purpose of this exercise) we may assume that the acceptable octal numbers start with `01 or 02` then such numbers are below 10000 decimal.

Then the numeric base for division/modulo and the type of output (`%d` for decimal or `%o` for octal) can be defined:

```java
public static String rotate(int x) {
    int    base = x < 10000 ? 0100 : 100;
    String type = x < 10000 ? "o" : "d";
    int[] d = {
        x % base,
        x / base % base,
        x / (base * base)
    };
    return String.format("%02" + type + ".%02" +  type + ".%02" + type, d[0], d[1], d[2]);
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(rotate(011112)); // octal
System.out.println(rotate(11112));  // decimal (no leading 0)
```

Output:

```
12.11.01
12.11.01
```